# Disk Partitioning

Tags: partitioning

I am trying to partition my disk so that I can install Linux on my laptop, and I have 4 partitions (all primary):

First 2 are C and D, but the other 2 are unknown to me.
one called *: which is 8.51 GB of size (2.80 GB used, no status) and the other one is called 
*:SYSTEM which is 16.47 GB (only 92.03 MB used, and the status is Active & Boot). Apparently there is a lot of memory never used but I wanted to check if this partitions are important, what are this 2 partitions used for because I cannot access them in any way, and how much can I re-size them without crashing anything.

Thanks

if it's of any use my OS is Win 7 Home Prem SP1 64 bit.

Comment: @NickRosencrantz Please don't suggest users to ask their questions on multiple sites, especially when their question can be migrated automatically to a site where it's on topic. This will only encourage cross-posting. Just vote to close/migrate and don't leave a comment. Tural Neymanov, please **do not post this question** on another site. It is on topic here and there's no need to duplicate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the OS which came from factory? I mean when you bought the laptop this is the OS which came with it? If yea, those partitions are probrably recovery partitions. I would format everything, reinstall windows and install ubuntu on the other partition.